# how to restore the database backup of sqlite in andorid for non rooted device

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to restore the bike_info.db to my application
the db file has some records and I want to restore them in the app

I tried with below code,  toast successful is displayed but db is not getting restored, I don't know why. can anyone help?

```
rest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cview_restore);

    rest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                if (sd.canWrite()) {

                    String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "com.infyco.kp.new_tab"
                            + "//databases//" + "bike_info.db";
                    String backupDBPath = "//data//bike_info.db"; // From SD directory.
                    File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                    File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Successful!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        }
        });
```

after clicking on rest button this is the output from android monitor:

```
01-17 14:00:40.922 8909-8909/com.infyco.kp.new_tab D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-17 14:00:40.962 8909-8909/com.infyco.kp.new_tab D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

01-17 14:00:41.012 8909-8909/com.infyco.kp.new_tab D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{9ba3ae9 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102039d android:id/toast_layout_root}

01-17 14:00:41.072 8909-8909/com.infyco.kp.new_tab D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1

01-17 14:00:43.022 8909-8909/com.infyco.kp.new_tab D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the core restore code from a working restore. A few differences:
I flush before close.

I rename the original DB (make a copy and delete the original) thus it doesn't exist (easy to revert back if the restore fails).

I also do it in it's own thread (not shown here).

I get the path/filename of the database from the system.

```
                dbfile = new File(currentdbfilename);    
                .......             
                try {
                    // Stage 1 Create a copy of the database
                    Log.i(logtag, "Stage 1 (make Copy of current DB)Starting");
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbfile);
                    OutputStream backup = new FileOutputStream(copydbfilename);
                    while ((copylength = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        backup.write(buffer, 0, copylength);
                    }
                    backup.flush();
                    backup.close();
                    fis.close();
                    Log.i(logtag, "Stage 1 - Complete. Copy made of current DB.");
                    copytaken = true;

                    // Stage 2 - Delete the database file
                    if (dbfile.delete()) {
                        Log.i(logtag, "Stage 2 - Completed. Original DB deleted.");
                        origdeleted = true;
                    }

                    // Stage 3 copy from the backup to the deleted database file i.e. create it
                    Log.i(logtag, "Stage 3 - (Create new DB from backup) Starting.");
                    FileInputStream bkp = new FileInputStream(backupfilename);
                    OutputStream restore = new FileOutputStream(currentdbfilename);
                    copylength = 0;
                    while ((copylength = bkp.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        restore.write(buffer, 0, copylength);
                    }
                    Log.i(logtag, "Stage 3 - Data Written");
                    restore.flush();
                    restore.close();
                    Log.i(logtag, "Stage 3 - New DB file flushed and closed");
                    restoredone = true;
                    bkp.close();
                    Log.i(logtag, "Stage 3 - Complete.");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if(!copytaken) {
                        errlist.add("Restore failed copying current database. Error was " + e.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        if(!origdeleted) {
                            errlist.add("Restore failed to delete current database. Error was " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        else {
                            if(!restoredone) {
                                errlist.add("Restore failed to recreate the database from the backup. Error was "+ e.getMessage());
                                errlist.add("Restore will attempt to revert to the original database.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**currentdbfilename** is set using :-

```
            currentdbfilename = this.getDatabasePath(
                DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME)
                .getPath();
```

**copydbfilename** is selected from a list of available backups via  a spinner (a slight difference is that the backup are in external storage public).